# VisualSFM build

Tags: macos, build, 3d

I have zero prior knowledge on doing this kind of thing, but I'm trying to install [VisualSFM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/install.html#mac) on a mac running  Yosemite. I've got through the entire build process using an [installer](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer) and I'm now stuck on the final steps with this error message in Terminal:

```
About to make...
mkdir -p build
mkdir -p bin 
cd build; ar -x ../lib/VisualSFM.a; cd ..;
g++-4.8 -w -o bin/VisualSFM build/*.* -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -pthread -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -ldl -L/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.28_2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.36.8_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.16.0/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.2_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.30.8/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.44.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgtk-quartz-2.0 -lgdk-quartz-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  lib/lapack.a lib/blas.a lib/libf2c.a lib/libjpeg.a 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gdk_x11_drawable_get_xdisplay", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::CreatePaintWnd()       in RegisterGUI.o
  "_gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::CreatePaintWnd()       in RegisterGUI.o
  "_gdk_x11_window_get_drawable_impl", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::CreatePaintWnd()       in RegisterGUI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [VisualSFM] Error 1
VSFM application failed to build, halting.
```

Anyone have any suggestions for a complete novice (but pretty good with tinkering and figuring things out...)??

Cheers!

Comment: exact same problem here, btw

Comment: Turns out heaps of people do @user655489, we're working through it with the maker of the installer [here](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer/issues/7#issuecomment-126440539).